# Android Studio 3.0 shortcut SHIFT + ESCAPE not closing run view?

Tags: android, macos, shortcut, android-studio-3.0, keymapping

I'm using ***Android Studio 3.0*** and operating system version is ***MacOs High Sierra Version 10.13.1***.

I have an issue where SHIFT+ESCAPE command is not a closing **Run** window in Android Studio. I tried different key mappings, but it also doesn't work. Click on the close button does work.

Other AS setup params that might clarify the situation:

> Android Studio keymaps: Mac OS X 10.5+
>
> *Run* window is in floating mode.

[image: Preview]

Is this some known Android Studio bug or it might be that my OS is intercepting commands?

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Gave +1 for "SHIT + ESCAPE"

Comment: Damn, tnx for the correction xD

Comment: i  needed that (a laugh) thx .

Answer (score 0):

So, the keystroke from Android Studio 2.x stopped working in 3.0. Looks like a bug in Android Studio 3.0 as it works for me in Android Studio 2.3.2 on the same macOS version.